# Synchronize users from active directory using SAML

Tags: active-directory, ldap, saml

I implemented the authentication process using SAML. In my project I have a rotine to synchronization users from active directory. Someone knows possible problems in synchronization using the SAML since that the Identity Provider will be in another domain accessed by the web ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SAML is only an authentication protocol. There is no mechanism in SAML for synchronizing directory contents (such as users).

You will have to look at other protocols than SAML to solve that.